# MediaCodec decoder.configure giving illegalstateexception

Tags: android-mediaplayer, codec, android-mediacodec

I am trying to extract frames from video using MediaCodec.
I am trying to run the following example first http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt

```
String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
try
{
    decoder.configure(format, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
}
```

I get **IllegalStateException**.
I am new to using mediaCodecs. Please Help.

```
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 0);
```

the above line of code does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start decoder after configuring, like that:

```
String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder.configure(format, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);
decoder.start();
```